# Link Entity Framework to datatable row

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am trying to convert a query to a datatable which will be shown in datagridview so they can select the corresponding row.

I get this error:

> Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType1`5[System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Int32]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store <{ id_moNumber = 66856, moNumber1 = 81262, moOrder = 27208, moClient = Rawlings, moQty = 26 }> in ID Num Column.  Expected type is Int32."}

My code is as follows:

```
foreach (var badMO in badMOs)
{
    var possibleFixes = dbReports.MoNumbers
                .Where(q => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(badMO.moNumber) && 
                            (q.moNumber1 == badMO.moNumber || 
                             q.moOrder == badMO.moNumber)) || 
                            (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(badMO.moOrder) && 
                            (q.moOrder == badMO.moOrder || q.moNumber1 == badMO.moOrder)))
                .Select(s => new { s.id_moNumber, s.moNumber1, 
                                   s.moOrder, s.moClient, s.moQty })
                .ToList();

    foreach (var moFound in possibleFixes) 
    {
         dtFixes.Rows.Add(possibleFixes.ToArray()); 
    }

    curJob.Rows.Add(badMOs);
    MOFixForm fixForm = new MOFixForm(dtFixes, curJob);
    fixForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

I am getting the error at `foreach moFound in possibleFixes`.

Looking at it I am really close but I don't understand what to convert the query to make it work with `IConvertible`

Comment: What is `dtFixes`?

Comment: You need to answer questions if you want help. what is `dtFixes`? Show the code for that please.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this part...

```
dtFixes.Rows.Add(possibleFixes.ToArray());
```

...by this...

```
dtFixes.Rows.Add(moFound);
```

You are adding the whole list for each line in the grid instead of just your current item.

The same applies for:

```
curJob.Rows.Add(badMOs);
```

It should be:

```
curJob.Rows.Add(badMO);
```